# Python multiple inheritance only working for one parent's method but calling method from both parents

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-testing

I have a `Python`/`OOP` question. 
You are all familiar with diamond problem in `C++` right? This is something similar.
I have the following classes

```
class BaseAuth(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # create dummy user and client, removing code of that for simplicity.
        self.user.save()
        self.client.save()

    def _get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        pass

class TokenAuthTests(BaseAuth):

    def _get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        super()._get_authenticated_api_client()
        print("I AM IN TOKEN AUTH")
        api_client = APIClient()
        # do stuff with api_client
        return api_client

class BasicAuthTests(BaseAuth):

    def _get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        super()._get_authenticated_api_client()
        print("I AM IN BASIC AUTH")
        api_client = APIClient()
        # do stuff with api client
        return api_client

class ClientTestCase(BasicAuthTests, TokenAuthTests):

    def test_get_login_response(self):
        api_client = self._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # login test code

    def test_get_clients(self):
        api_client = self._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # get client test code

    def test_get_client_by_id(self):
        api_client = self._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # get client by id test code

    def test_update_client_by_id(self):
        api_client = self._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # update client test code

    def test_add_client(self):
        api_client = self._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # add client test code

    def test_delete_client_by_id(self):
        api_client = self._get_authenticated_api_client()
        # delete client test code
```

Now, when I run the code, I can see that this is printed out:

```
I AM IN TOKEN AUTH
I AM IN BASIC AUTH
.I AM IN TOKEN AUTH
I AM IN BASIC AUTH
.I AM IN TOKEN AUTH
I AM IN BASIC AUTH
.I AM IN TOKEN AUTH
I AM IN BASIC AUTH
.I AM IN TOKEN AUTH
I AM IN BASIC AUTH
.I AM IN TOKEN AUTH
I AM IN BASIC AUTH
```

But if I see functionality wise, the tests run for only `BasicAuthTests`. How do I know this?
1. The number of test runs is `6`, when it should be `12`, `6` with each parent class.
2. If I change the `_get_authenticated_api_client()` function in `BasicAuthTests` to wrong `return` type, the code crashes but if I change it in `TokenAuthTests` nothing happens, which means, the `TokenAuthTests` is not doing anything, but its print statement in working which means function is called.
This is so confusing, can somebody please help?
My ultimate goal here is to run these 6 tests for each of the parent class's returned `api_client`.

> HERE IS MUST MENTION THAT, THE CODE RUNS FINE. AND THE TEST WORK ALRIGHT IF I RUN THEM SEPARATELY. I AM TRYING TO SIMPLIFY THE CODE AND REMOVE ALL THE REPETITION, THAT'S WHY I AM KIND TO TRYING TO MERGE THEM INTO ONE FILE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem by using a different approach.
What we can do is, we can declare all the tests in a parent class and declare the function `_get_authenticated_api_client` in child classes.
But how can we use a child class's function in parent class? 
When parent class inherits `TestCase` and will be the first class from which tests will be run and it will crash because it won't have `_get_authenticated_api_client` function.
To avoid this what we do is we wrap the parent class in another class, this way that class will not be treated as a class but as an object of parent class.
But when we inherit our child classes from that wrapped parent `TestCase` inherited class, it will be treated like class and it's tests will be run but at that point the `_get_authenticated_api_client` function will be declared in child.
Here's the code

```
class WrapperTestClass:

    class ClientTestCase(TestCase):

        # all the tests and setup function

class TokenAuthTests(WrapperTestClass.ClientTestCase):

    def get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        # function that returns api_client

class BasicAuthTests(WrapperTestClass.ClientTestCase):

    def get_authenticated_api_client(self):
        # function that returns api_client
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting stuck withour your [MRO](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=mro#class.mro).
While Python supports [Diamond Inheritance](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/12217-programmers-python-mutliple-inheritance.html?start=1), you will get stuck when it comes to variable assignment.

Thanks to [Diamond Inheritance](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/12217-programmers-python-mutliple-inheritance.html?start=1), we now both `_get_authenticated_api_client` will be called. When it comes to assignement, what `_get_authenticated_api_client` returns depends on order you pass your classes.

In your case, only 6 tests ran beacause you only have one class, with 6 tests functions.

You intend to run the exact same tests, with different `auth` mehtods.
One easy way of doing this is:

```py
class ClientMixinCase: #Do not Inherit from "TestCase"
    #... Declare you tests here

class ClientWithTokenAuthTestCase(ClientMixinCase,TokenAuthTests):
    pass

class ClientWithBasicAuthTestCase(ClientMixinCase,BasicAuthTests):
    pass
```

Comment: I created this structure, and ran but no tests ran. I pasted the tests from `ClientTestCase` under `ClientMixinCase`. Is there something I am expected to put in place of `pass`?

Comment: Try changing order in `ClientMixinCase` and `TokenAuthTests`

Comment: And both `TokenAuthTests` and `BasicAuthTests` somehow extends `TestCase`?